# Bokeh tooltips not displaying player names, but displaying other data correctly

Tags: python, bokeh

I am working on creating a scatter plot using Bokeh in a Jupyter Notebook to visualize player data. The scatter plot should display player names in tooltips when I hover over data points. However, I'm encountering an issue where the player names are not displaying in the tooltips, but other data (such as Wage and Value) is displayed correctly.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool`

# Data
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
x = player_info['Wage']
y = player_info['Value']
Name = player_info['Name'].astype(str)
# Hover tooltips
TOOLTIPS = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("(Wage,Value)", "(@x, @y)"),
    ("Name", "@Name")
])
# Creating the plot
p = figure(title='soccer', width=400, height=400,x_axis_label='Wage', y_axis_label='Value',         tools=[TOOLTIPS])
p.circle(x, y, fill_color='red', size=10)
# Show the plot
show(p)
```

[**output screenshot**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ucFTz.png)

I've tried several troubleshooting steps to resolve the issue, including:

1.**Data Verification**: Ensured that player_info['Name'] contains valid player names as strings.

2.**Explicit String Conversion:** Explicitly converted the Name column to strings using .astype(str) to make sure it contains string data.

3.**Bokeh Update:** Updated Bokeh to the latest version using pip install --upgrade bokeh.

4.**Kernel Restart:** Restarted the Jupyter Notebook kernel to rule out any issues related to the notebook's state.

5.**Browser Inspection:** Checked the browser console for JavaScript errors while running the code. No JavaScript errors were reported.

6.**Browser Compatibility:** Tested the code in different web browsers to ensure the issue is not browser-specific.

Despite these efforts, the player names are still not displaying correctly in the tooltips, and I continue to see "Name: ??" when hovering over the data points

Comment: You haven't actually included the "Name" column in the generated plot. In order to do that you need to create a `ColumnDataSource` yourself, with all the data you want, and drive the plot with that, rather than passing the data directly to `circle`. https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/basic/data.html

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Python code snippet using Bokeh to create a scatter plot for soccer player data with tooltips. This code assumes you have a DataFrame named player_info containing columns 'Wage', 'Value', and 'Name'. The plot will show the relationship between player wages and their market values, with tooltips displaying player names, indices, wages, and values when hovering over the data points.

```
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import HoverTool, ColumnDataSource

# Assuming you have a DataFrame named player_info
x = player_info['Wage']
y = player_info['Value']
Name = player_info['Name']

# Create a ColumnDataSource to hold the data
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, y=y, Name=Name))

# Define tooltips for the HoverTool
TOOLTIPS = HoverTool(tooltips=[
    ("index", "$index"),
    ("Name", "@Name"),
    ("(Wage, Value)", "(@x, @y)"),
])

# Create the figure
p = figure(title='Soccer Player Data', width=400, height=400, 
x_axis_label='Wage', y_axis_label='Value', tools=[TOOLTIPS])

# Add circles to the plot
p.circle(source=source, fill_color='red', size=10)

# Show the plot
show(p)
```

**Explanation:**

1.We import the necessary modules from Bokeh: figure, show, HoverTool, and ColumnDataSource.

2.We extract the 'Wage', 'Value', and 'Name' columns from the player_info DataFrame and create a ColumnDataSource to hold this data.

3.We define tooltips for the HoverTool to display the player's index, name, and the wage and value when hovering over a data point.

4.We create a figure object with labels for the x-axis and y-axis and add the HoverTool to the list of tools.

5.Finally, we use circle to add data points to the plot and use show to display the plot.